# Error "was not declared in this scope" in function

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

I have following function in my include (`.h`) file:

```
string genPassword(char[] alphabet = {}, int length=0)
{
    string s = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        s += alphabet[rand() % (sizeof(alphabet) - 1)];
    }
    random_shuffle(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}
```

When I try to compile it with `g++` (to check is everything working) I see following errors:

> g++ -Wall -c "passfunctions.h" (w katalogu /home/bla/programs)
>
> passfunctions.h:22:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘alphabet’
>
> string genPassword(char[] alphabet = {}, int length=0)
>
> ```
>                        ^
> ```
>
> passfunctions.h: In function ‘std::string genPassword(char*)’:
>
> passfunctions.h:25:23: error: ‘length’ was not declared in this scope
>
> for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
>
> ```
>                    ^
> ```
>
> passfunctions.h:26:14: error: ‘alphabet’ was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> ```
>      s += alphabet[rand() % (sizeof(alphabet) - 1)];
>
>           ^
> ```
>
> Compilation failed.

I do not understand those errors. Why semicolon is expected before `alphabet` in function declaration?...

Why two next errors shows the variables declared in function are "not declared in this scope"? Please explain me what do I do wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong. You need something like

```
string genPassword(char alphabet[] = {}, int length=0);
                                ^^
```

Note 1: This is a function *declaration*. If you have a separate function *definition*, omit the default parameter values:

```
string genPassword(char alphabet[], int length) { .... }
```

If you want to define the function at the point of declaration in the header, then mark it `inline` to avoid multiple definitions:

```
inline string genPassword(char alphabet[] = {}, int length=0)
{
  ....
}
```

Note 2: `alphabet` is really a `char*` in this context, so it may make sense to set the default value to `nullptr`. Also note that `sizeof(alhpabet)` is the size of a `char*`, not the size of an array (thanks to @RaymondChen for pointing that out.)

Comment: Note also that since `alphabet` is a `char *`, the `sizeof(alphabet)` does not do what you think.

Comment: Not formally wrong, but since he's not modifying `alphabet` in his function (and it probably makes sense to call the function with a string literal), it should really be `char const* alphabet`.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare default arguments in the function declaration. Try this in your header:

```
string genPassword(char[] = {}, int length=0);
```

And then define it like this in your .cpp file:

```
string genPassword(char* alphabet, int length)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do I have to do that in the header file before exact function declaration?

Comment: @Ty221 I clarified in my edit

Comment: Why my header file couldn't contain function's code?

Comment: Can you expalin me that?

Comment: This would only apply if the declaration and body were separate, but given that the code is defined in one place (header file), then the default parameters should be fine as they are (and how would this trigger a problem *before* `alphabet`?)